# Statistical analysis in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, statistics

I have an application built using C# Winforms, data in a SQL Server database, some built-in analytics, and reports that are displayed using DataGridView.

However, I want that to be extensible. I want the user to be able to tranform the data - add more columns, group by the data by certain columns etc. (functionality similar to SPSS or other statistical tools).

Are there any frameworks to do this?
Can I use any of the stat tools behind the scene to do this?

Comment: DevExpress PivotGrid http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Pivot_Grid/, but it's commercial component which is quite expensive

Comment: Thanks MishaU. That seems to be close to what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look at Microsoft SQL Reporting Services. You can use the reportviewer control into the winforms app.

Comment: ykatchou, I am looking for more end-user capabilities, which does not seem possible with the report viewer. Let me know if I am wrong. Thanks for the response.